# How to get the following integral: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-|x|}dx=?$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> How to get the following integral:
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-|x|}dx=?$$
>   where $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$

I know 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-|x|}dx=2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use *spherical coordinates*:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-|x|}dx= \int_{r \in (0, + \infty)} \int_{\theta \in (0, \pi)} \int_{\varphi \in (0, 2\pi)}r^2 e^{-r} \sin(\theta) \text{d}\theta \text{d}r \text{d}\varphi $$

Comment: Is the result 1?

Comment: Don't think so (I haven't done the computations so far :-)). Do you know how to compute the integral $\int r^2e^{-r} \text{d}r$ ?

Comment: I get the $8\pi$. But what I want is 1...

Comment: Well, sometimes, as famously coined by Mick Jagger, "you can't always get what you want" :-). The result is $8\pi$ indeed !

Comment: But the textbook requires its integral is 1... Since it is a probability density.

Comment: Well that's a mistake, I guess ! You need to divide by $8 \pi$ is order to get a probability density.

Comment: Is $\int_{R^3} |e^{-(1/2) |x|}|^2 =\int_{R^3} e^{- |x|}$, right?

Comment: Yes; of course. What's your point ?